# Validate dicts in Python

Tags: python, validation, dictionary, schema, associative-array

i looking for tool, or examples to/how to validate dictionaries in python.
For example, i have dict:

```
test = {'foo' : 'bar', 'nested' : {'foo1' : 'bar1', 'foo2' : 'bar2'} }
```

And now i must validate it. Lets say, value for key `foo` must be boolean **False** or non-empty string. Next, if key `foo1` have value `bar1`, that key `foo2` **must** be int in range `1..10`. I wrote simple function to do this, but this is not what i exactly want. Yea, sure, i can test every single item in dict with `if..else`, but if dict have >50 elements, then it is a bit not comfortable.

Is there any good tool/lib to do this in Python? I not looking for parsers, only *fast* and effective way to do this right.

Comment: this is a rare case. I think there are no parsers for this specific task. Maybe you can use `map` function over dict.

Comment: **See also**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45346374/python-schema-to-have-at-least-one-key

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Voluptous is a nice tool that does this
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/voluptuous

Comment: Exactly what i want. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

You can also try the link below:
https://github.com/sunlightlabs/validictory
Its a great package that helps in validation in an easier way

Comment: Depreciated from 2018, you need to use jsonschema instead.

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend [Cerberus](http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/) for its readability or [jsonschema](https://github.com/Julian/jsonschema) because it uses the [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/) standard

Answer (score 0):

Webster is a pypi package that does dictionary validation and value regex validation.. this allows you to insure that the dictionary has all the keys its supposed to and the values are more or less what you would expect.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Webster

Comment: since this was a 4 years old question with an already accepted answer it would better if you give more details. Are you proposing a more innovative solution ? If yes please explain it. Have you replicated the example proposed ?

Answer (score 0):

This [dict-schema-validator](https://github.com/andrey-ushakov/dict-schema-validator) package is a very simple way to validate python dictionaries.

Here is a simple schema representing a Customer:

```
{
  "_id":          "ObjectId",
  "created":      "date",
  "is_active":    "bool",
  "fullname":     "string",
  "age":          ["int", "null"],
  "contact": {
    "phone":      "string",
    "email":      "string"
  },
  "cards": [{
    "type":       "string",
    "expires":    "date"
  }]
}
```

Validation:

```
from datetime import datetime
import json
from dict_schema_validator import validator


with open('models/customer.json', 'r') as j:
    schema = json.loads(j.read())

customer = {
    "_id":          123,
    "created":      datetime.now(),
    "is_active":    True,
    "fullname":     "Jorge York",
    "age":          32,
    "contact": {
        "phone":    "559-940-1435",
        "email":    "york@example.com",
        "skype":    "j.york123"
    },
    "cards": [
        {"type": "visa", "expires": "12/2029"},
        {"type": "visa"},
    ]
}

errors = validator.validate(schema, customer)
for err in errors:
    print(err['msg'])
```

Output:

```
[*] "_id" has wrong type. Expected: "ObjectId", found: "int"
[+] Extra field: "contact.skype" having type: "str"
[*] "cards[0].expires" has wrong type. Expected: "date", found: "str"
[-] Missing field: "cards[1].expires"
```